# Composited PNG Image disapers in render

Tags: compositing-nodes, image, transparency

I am trying to composit some clouds into my render using the depth pass.
It works fine and looks good to me in the compositor but when I save the image as PNG with alpha, the clouds that are not overlaping the original rendered object are gone.

I attached a few screenshots. Can anyone help me bring back the clouds?

Thank you and have a good day,

Fabian

Compositor

[image]

How it should look (jpg without alpha)

[image]

How it looks

[image]

They really aren't there ;-)

[image]

Comment: Can you share your blend with packed images? Or just a part with issue still visible. Usually it is behaviour of emissive materials (pixels with value over 1) on top of transparency, but it doesn't seems to be a case. Try to save as OpenEXR 32-bit to see what happens. What Blender version you use?

Comment: @vklidu        Hello, thanks for your comment. Sadly the original file is to large but I created a simpler (and very ugly) one to show the problem. Maybe it helps.

https://we.tl/t-Hf31tAlSlf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of *Mix* node use **Alpha Over** node ...

[image]

[image]

Note: For proper mixing depth is designed *Z Combine* node, but it requires also cloud image to be rendered with *Depth* pass and saved as *OpenEXR Multilayer*.

Comment: Thank you very much vklidu. That does the trick. I have the feeling the colors are a litte different when i export it as PNG but I think its just the different background color.
I have never worked with OpenEXR before. This will be the next step I guess.

Have a good day! :-)

Comment: Great if it works for you ... alternatively you can mix Alpha channels (Math-Ad node) and use Set Alpha node ... https://imgur.com/xnYJDvx, but why to make things complicated :) Technically I'm not sure why alpha of cloud image is ignored, but there is a lot of issues with alpha now, so probably better not to search for troubles :)